# Cacti displaying graph text as blocks

Tags: linux, charts

[image]

(Image now irrelevant, it is grabbing the newest graph from my server.. I did not archive a picture of it when it was broken. Instead of text, each character was represented by a block.)

I had not been checking my graphs for a long time. There have been updates to the server since it last worked. Has anybody seen this before?

> Linux box 2.6.23-gentoo-r3 #1 SMP Fri Jan 11 21:08:20 EST 2008 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3220 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

Comment: Which font is specified for the display?

Comment: How do I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I needed to install a font. E.g. on Gentoo:

```
emerge media-fonts/dejavu
```

Comment: doh! thanks. not sure how this font got uninstalled (unmerged), as it worked correctly for a year.